# Style Display is flickering to display: none when set to 'block.'

Tags: javascript, html

I've been following a tutorial for creating a login window on a website, but when I click the 'openbtn,' the overlay briefly flashes before disappearing again. I'm a beginner at html and javascript, so I don't see where the issue could be. The code is attached before. The default overlay.style.display is set to none.

```
<div class="text-box">
        <h1>Meal Ticket Machine</h1>
        <p>Welcome to the store!</p>
        <a href="" class="openbtn" onclick="openForm()">Log in/ Register</a>
      </div>

      <div id = "myOverlay" class="overlay">
        <span class = "closebtn" onclick= "closeForm()" title = "Close Overlay"> &#215 </span>
        <div class="wrap">
          <h2>Sign Up Here</h2>
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder = "Username">
            <input type="text" placeholder = "Email">
            <input type="password" placeholder = "Password">
            <input type="password" placeholder = "Re-enter Password">
            <input type="submit" placeholder = "Start!">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
<!---- Javascript for login ---->

<script>
  function openForm(){
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
  }
  function closeForm(){
    document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add ```event.stopPropagation();``` to openForm function's first line to see if it will help.

Comment: No, there still is the same issue.

Comment: Either add ````event.preventDefault();``` to openForm function or use button instead of <a>Loging</a>. I tried, both worked.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!